# How to have a dynamic row number range

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to do the following in Excel:

Do something for the range $A$1:A(B1) with B1 being the value in cell B1. So that if I drag the formula down, the cell below gets the formula performed for the range of $A$1:A(B2)

Comment: I think a named range or [dynamic named-range](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html) could do the job for you.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What, exactly, do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, write a formula like the following:

```
=INDIRECT(  "$A$1:A"  &  B1)
```

The "$A$1:A" portion will always remain the same in it, but the cell reference outside that string is "live" as it were, and will change as you copy it down the column. Which seems like what you are looking for.

People focus on `INDIRECT()` a lot for formulas that won't "break" if a row or 4,000 or a column or 43 are inserted somewhere that would ruin a DIRECT formula especially in the circumstance of later deleting some or all of them. But it has the other main feature of being able to use BOTH strings AND live cells to build a reference it then interprets.

You can make them pretty complicated too. Some string, joined to a live cell, joined to some more string, joined to a formula that doesn't even reference a particular live cell, but does output something, joined to some more string perhaps... and so on. If it is a string you can build that ends up looking like a valid cell reference, `INDIRECT()` can then use it.

It can even refer to a Named Range though you have to remember not to use double quotes around it even though it feels like you're adding a string. So `INDIRECT(Cell_of_Interest)` and NOT `INDIRECT("Cell_of_Interest")`. But CREATING a Named Range in the string passed to `INDIRECT()` can be tricky so... if you have to pass a Named Range into it rather than type it in when you write the formula, that can be... spotty... in practice.